# C++: Creating "abstract class" with implemented functions

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I created a class to represent a vector (Vec3D), along with it's basic canonical operations (sum, scalar product, cross product, etc.). I will use this class to derive classes of real physical units (position, velocity, acceleration, force, etc.) which will have their own "exclusive" characteristics and operations, **in addition* to their vector operations.

I want Vec3D to be non-instanciable, since everything has to be a physical unit, but making it abstract would mean I have to re-define all the operators for each derived class again.

**What would be the best practice here, that allows me to leverage the already defined operators? (maybe defining the constructors as private, and the operators as public?**

and

**In which case would I need to use virtual functions?**

Below my base class:

```
class Vec3D
{
private:
  double _x;
  double _y;
  double _z;

protected:
  // Constructors / Destructor
  Vec3D(const double x, const double y, const double z);
  Vec3D();
  Vec3D(const Vec3D& source);
  Vec3D(Vec3D&& source);
  ~Vec3D(); // Declared just for completeness, although not necessary

public:
  // Operator Overloading
  Vec3D& operator=(const Vec3D& source);
  Vec3D& operator=(Vec3D&& source);
  Vec3D& operator+=(const Vec3D& source);
  Vec3D& operator+=(Vec3D&& source);
  Vec3D operator+(const Vec3D& source) const;
  Vec3D operator+(Vec3D&& source) const;
  Vec3D operator-() const;
  Vec3D& operator-=(const Vec3D& source);
  Vec3D& operator-=(Vec3D&& source);
  Vec3D operator-(const Vec3D& source)const;
  Vec3D operator-(Vec3D&& source) const;
  Vec3D operator*(const double source) const;
  double operator*(const Vec3D& source) const;
  double operator*(Vec3D&& source) const;
  Vec3D operator^(const Vec3D& source) const;
  Vec3D operator^(Vec3D&& source) const;
};
```

Thank you

Comment: You should not need assignment, copy or "move" functions (as well as the destructor). Use [*the rule of zero*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) and rely on the implicit operators and constructors generated by the compiler. Also, using both const lvalue and rvalue overloads for your operators makes no sense. Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware of that, but did not want to overcomplicate using dynamic member variables. The question i'm trying to answer is another though.

Comment: It's the opposite, by using non "dynamic" member variables, you can use the rule of zero, and don'y need `Vec3D(const Vec3D& source);`, `Vec3D(Vec3D&& source);`, `~Vec3D();`, `Vec3D& operator=(const Vec3D& source);` and `Vec3D& operator=(Vec3D&& source);`. You can just erase all those functions and copying and moving will *still* work as intended.

Comment: And you don't need both of `Vec3D operator-(const Vec3D& source)const;` and `Vec3D operator-(Vec3D&& source) const;`. Only the lvalue version of each function is needed. The same goes for all other functions as well.

Comment: Lastly about your problem about making it not possible to create instances of `Vec3D`, making the constructors `protected` is enough.

Comment: Got it: So would you say that the best practice is: If I want to use an unstantiable base class, but implement some methods that will be used for all of the derived classes I cannot use an abstract class? Is the point of an abstract class only to define a template of function declarations and member variables? Sounds to me like abstract classes are then used not very often, since there will more often than not be overlap of some equal methods. (I'm new to abstract classes / polymorphism :), btw.)

Comment: Actually, you *can't* create what you seem to want. The assignment operators *must* be members of the actual class being assigned to, you can't offload that to a base-class.

Comment: You also can't have something like `Vec3D operator-(Vec3D&& source) const;` in a base-class, as that would lead to [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing). The operator as declared will always return a `Vec3D` object, no matter what.

Comment: In that case you're right, but then what is the best way of avoiding code redundance/repetition? How would **you** implement it personally?

Comment: Your design doesn't quite work, for a couple of reasons. First, since `Vec3D` is not instantiateable, all methods that return `Vec3D` are uncallable, and therefore totally unneeded. Second, all methods that accept a `Vec3D` reference are dangerous, because they are callable with a wrong vector type (adding velocity to position makes no sense). What you are trying to do is a rather complex task. I recommend studying existing libraries that deal with physical quantities, such as Boost.Units, before trying to make your own.

Comment: I like your input n.pronouns, that's an important distinction. In general this was an exercise to get a grasp on virtual vs non-virtual functions, so it's not that i'm trying to specifically implement a physical unit library.

Comment: Well, you have a set of related types that need to implement similar binary operations, and this is a hard computer-science-y problem, regardless of the exact nature of the relationship between your types. They may represent different physical quantities or different machine types (float vs double vs int etc) or different abstract algebraic structures (groups or rings or whatever). Virtual functions and OOP in general don't work well in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution to your problem you could do something similar to what I recently did myself for work.

I used a combination of inheritance using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) as a [*mixin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), and then macros for the assignment-operators.

For your case your assignment operators could off-load the actual implementation to the base-class using normal protected member functions.

Perhaps it could be something like this:

```
template<typename RealVec>
class VecBase
{
public:
    friend RealVec operator+(RealVec lhs, RealVec const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs += rhs;
    }

    friend RealVec operator*(RealVec lhs, RealVec const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs *= rhs;
    }

protected:
    // Compound addition and assignment
    RealVec& add_assign_this(RealVec& lhs, RealVec const& rhs)
    {
        // To prevent self-assignment
        if (&lhs != &rhs)
        {
            lhs._x += rhs._x;
            lhs._y += rhs._y;
            lhs._z += rhs._z;
        }
        return lhs;
    }

    // Compound multiplication and assignment
    RealVec& mul_assign_this(RealVec& lhs, RealVec const& rhs)
    {
        // To prevent self-assignment
        if (&lhs != &rhs)
        {
            lhs._x *= rhs._x;
            lhs._y *= rhs._y;
            lhs._z *= rhs._z;
        }
        return lhs;
    }

    // Plain assignment, =
    RealVec& assign_this(RealVec& lhs, RealVec const& rhs)
    {
        // To prevent self-assignment
        if (&lhs != &rhs)
        {
            static_cast<VecBase&>(lhs) = rhs;
        }
        return lhs;
    }

    // Protected constructors to inhibit instantiation
    VecBase()
        : _x{ 0 }, _y{ 0 }, _z{ 0 }
    {
    }

    VecBase(int x, int y, int z)
        : _x{ x }, _y{ y }, _z{ z }
    {
    }

    VecBase(VecBase const&) = default;
    VecBase(VecBase&&) = default;

private:
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _z;

    // The default assignment operator will do the correct thing, no need to implement it
    VecBase& operator=(VecBase const&) = default;
};

class Vector3D : public VecBase<Vector3D>
{
public:
    // Unfortunately we need to reimplement the constructors,
    // but can "call" the base constructors
    Vector3D()
        : VecBase<Vector3D>{ }
    {
    }

    Vector3D(int x, int y, int z)
        : VecBase<Vector3D>{ x, y, z }
    {
    }

    Vector3D(Vector3D const& other)
        : VecBase<Vector3D>(other)
    {
    }


#define DEFINE_COMPOUND_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR(oper, func)           \
    Vector3D& operator oper (Vector3D const& rhs)                 \
    {                                                             \
        return VecBase<Vector3D>::func##_assign_this(*this, rhs); \
    }

    DEFINE_COMPOUND_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR(+=, add)
    DEFINE_COMPOUND_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR(*=, mul)

#undef DEFINE_COMPOUND_ASSIGNMENT_OPERATOR

    // We still need to explicitly define the plain assignment operator
    Vector3D& operator=(Vector3D const& rhs)
    {
        return VecBase<Vector3D>::assign_this(*this, rhs);
    }
};
```

<sub>[[See it running on the Compiler Explorer site](https://godbolt.org/z/sqa6PfjeM)]</sub>

It's still a lot to write in the inherited classes, and unfortunately it can't really be avoided.